# Group hash keys contained within range of numbers

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I have a dataset of the combined attempts of several different approaches 
(`approaches 1 to 3`) to identify positions in a genome:

```
source  chromosome1 bp1 chromosome2 bp2
attempt1    2L  5890205 2L  5890720
attempt2    2L  5890205 2L  5890721
attempt1    2L  22220720    2L  22255744
attempt1    3L  15568694    3L  15568866
attempt3    3R  14006279    3R  14008254
attempt1    3R  14006281    3R  14008253
attempt2    3R  14006282    3R  14008254
attempt3    3R  14006286    3R  14008254
attempt1    3R  32060908    3R  32061196
attempt1    3R  32066206    3R  32068392
attempt3    3R  32066206    3R  32068392
attempt2    3R  32066207    3R  32068393
attempt2    X   4574312 X   4576608
attempt1    X   4574313 X   4576607
attempt3    X   4574313 X   4576608
```

I want to find and group positions that each attempt has identified, allowing a bit of room for error. For example, I would like to class the first two lines...

```
source  chromosome1 bp1 chromosome2 bp2
attempt1    2L  5890205 2L  5890720
attempt2    2L  5890205 2L  5890721
```

...as a single event (`event 1`), that has been identified by two different attempts (`attempt1` and `attempt2`). I want to class such instances as single events only if different attempts:

- Agree on the position of `bp1` `+/-` 5 (i.e. within the window `5890200..5890210`)
- Identify the same `chromosome1` and `chromosome2` (`2L`)
- Agree on the position of `bp2` `+/-` 5 (i.e. within the window `5890715..5890725`)

I have tried to achieve this using a each chromosome and bp as a separate key in a hash

```
my %SVs;
my $header;

# Make hash 
while(<$in>){
  chomp;
  if ($. == 1){
      $header = $_;
      next;
  }
  my ($source, $chromosome1, $bp1, $chromosome2, $bp2) = split;

  push @{$SVs{$chromosome1}{$bp1}{$chromosome2}{$bp2}}, $_;

  }
}
```

... and then using a sliding window approach around each bp1 and bp2 value for each line:

```
my %events;
for my $chr1 ( sort keys %SVs ){
  for my $bp1 ( sort { $a <=> $b } keys $SVs{$chr1} ){
    my $w1_start = ( $bp1 - 5 );
    my $w1_end = ( $bp1 + 5 );
    my $window1 = "$w1_start-$w1_end";

    for my $chr2 ( sort keys $SVs{$chr1}{$bp1} ){
      for my $bp2 ( sort { $a <=> $b } keys $SVs{$chr1}{$bp1}{$chr2} ){

        my $w2_start = ( $bp2 - 5 );
        my $w2_end = ( $bp2 + 5 );
        my $window2 = "$w2_start-$w2_end";

        for ( $w1_start .. $w1_end ){
          if ($bp1 == $_){
            push @{$events{$chr1}{$window1}}, @{$SVs{$chr1}{$bp1}{$chr2}{$bp2}};
          }
        }

        for ( $w2_start .. $w2_end ){
          if ($bp2 == $_){
            push @{$events{$chr2}{$window2}}, @{$SVs{$chr1}{$bp1}{$chr2}{$bp2}};
          }
        }

      }
    }
  }
}

print Dumper \%events;
```

This achieves part of what I'm want, but I can't work out how get my desired output:

```
event   source  chromosome1 bp1 chromosome2 bp2
1   attempt1    2L  5890205 2L  5890720
1   attempt2    2L  5890205 2L  5890721
2   attempt1    2L  22220720    2L  22255744
3   attempt1    3L  15568694    3L  15568866
4   attempt3    3R  14006279    3R  14008254
4   attempt1    3R  14006281    3R  14008253
4   attempt2    3R  14006282    3R  14008254
4   attempt3    3R  14006286    3R  14008254
5   attempt1    3R  32060908    3R  32061196
6   attempt1    3R  32066206    3R  32068392
6   attempt3    3R  32066206    3R  32068392
6   attempt2    3R  32066207    3R  32068393
7   attempt2    X   4574312 X   4576608
7   attempt1    X   4574313 X   4576607
7   attempt3    X   4574313 X   4576608
```

Comment: What if you have three attempts, and #1 and #2 agree, and #2 and #3 agree (but #1 and #3 does not agree). What event should then attempt #2 belong to?

Comment: Good question. That would suggest to me that they should be grouped, and I would then want to expand my window (e.g. to +/- 10) to allow for this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The below defines each equivalence class by the last entry added to the equivalence class (based on my understanding of your comment above):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

run(\*DATA);

sub run {
    my $fh = shift;
    my @header = split ' ', scalar <$fh>;

    my @events = ([ get_next_event($fh, \@header)]);

    while (my $event = get_next_event($fh, \@header)) {
        # change the -1 in the second subscript to 0
        # if you want to always compare to the first
        # event added to the equivalence class
        if (same_event($events[-1][-1], $event, 5)) {
            push @{ $events[-1] }, $event;
            next;
        }

        push @events, [ $event ];
    }

    print join("\t", event => @header), "\n";
    for my $i (1 .. @events) {
        for my $ev (@{ $events[$i - 1] }) {
            print join("\t", $i, @{$ev}{@header}), "\n";
        }
    }
}

sub get_next_event {
    my $fh = shift;
    my $header = shift;
    return unless defined(my $line = <$fh>);
    return unless $line =~ /\S/;

    my %event;
    @event{ @$header } = split ' ', $line;
    return \%event;
}

sub same_event {
    my ($x, $y, $threshold) = @_;

    return if $x->{chromosome1} ne $y->{chromosome1};
    return if abs($x->{bp1} - $y->{bp1}) > $threshold;
    return if abs($x->{bp2} - $y->{bp2}) > $threshold;
    return 1;
}

__DATA__
source  chromosome1 bp1 chromosome2 bp2
attempt1    2L  5890205 2L  5890720
attempt2    2L  5890205 2L  5890721
attempt1    2L  22220720    2L  22255744
attempt1    3L  15568694    3L  15568866
attempt3    3R  14006279    3R  14008254
attempt1    3R  14006281    3R  14008253
attempt2    3R  14006282    3R  14008254
attempt3    3R  14006286    3R  14008254
attempt1    3R  32060908    3R  32061196
attempt1    3R  32066206    3R  32068392
attempt3    3R  32066206    3R  32068392
attempt2    3R  32066207    3R  32068393
attempt2    X   4574312 X   4576608
attempt1    X   4574313 X   4576607
attempt3    X   4574313 X   4576608
```

Output:

```
event   source  chromosome1 bp1 chromosome2 bp2
1   attempt1    2L  5890205 2L  5890720
1   attempt2    2L  5890205 2L  5890721
2   attempt1    2L  22220720    2L  22255744
3   attempt1    3L  15568694    3L  15568866
4   attempt3    3R  14006279    3R  14008254
4   attempt1    3R  14006281    3R  14008253
4   attempt2    3R  14006282    3R  14008254
4   attempt3    3R  14006286    3R  14008254
5   attempt1    3R  32060908    3R  32061196
6   attempt1    3R  32066206    3R  32068392
6   attempt3    3R  32066206    3R  32068392
6   attempt2    3R  32066207    3R  32068393
7   attempt2    X   4574312 X   4576608
7   attempt1    X   4574313 X   4576607
7   attempt3    X   4574313 X   4576608
```

Comment: This works brilliantly. Could you explain what `unless (@{ $events[-1] }) ` is doing?

Comment: @fugu Streamlined code a little to get rid of that check. In principle, you should also check if reading the header and the first line of data succeeded, but I am guessing the input is somewhat under your control.